# on a rails 5 demo application getting an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ArticlesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show  
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ArticlesController#create
>   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #14):

```
12 def create
13   @article = Article.new(params[:article])
14 
15   @article.save
16   redirect_to @article
17 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you, it has nothing to do with rails version

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show  
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    private
      def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
      end
end
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I forgot to call the function.